Grant rights to create tables in a particular Oracle schema
What is the correct procedure for allowing team members to develop applications and create tables in only a specific schema?
I am running Oracle 12C. If I create a schema - say MYAPP1 - how should I grant permissions to Tom, Dick & Harry only to create tables in that schema?
If I do:
grant create any table to user tom

would that automatically grant him the right to create tables in any other schema? Furthermore, how would he get select, insert, update, delete rights to the table that he created?
Can this be done using roles so I can dynamically add / remove users to roles and not need to grant permissions every time the team changes?

Have you looked at proxy authentication?

um... appears more complicated than my current knowledge of Oracle. Can this be done without using additional components?

No, you either use proxy authentication, or you allow them to log in directly as the schema owner. Those are the choices. Proxy was designed for exactly your situation. And it doesn't require any additional components. Just a grant and a different way to log on.

You don't need any additional components, and it's not very complicated; look at the second half of this answer (from "You mentioned that you are trying to avoid...") for an example. You haven't said how your applications connect, but JDBC supports proxy authentication, for example.

Also maybe look at this answer and this answer for why ANY privileges shouldn't be used and alternative approaches, but I prefer proxy authentication as it's easier to set up and manage.

@PaulW  As per the first comment, that page says that I'd need to set up a second server to act as middle tier and perform authentications. That would entail new VM's, database licenses and so on. At the moment, I am using IBM DB2 where I do have a setup to allow dev team to create tables only in the project's schema. I am attempting to do the same in Oracle.

@AlexPoole Re your point on how the app connects: It uses a JNDI connection and a user id which has select, insert rights without create table permissions.

Your link also mentions DBA> alter user SAMPLE_SCHEMA grant connect through CIDBADMIN; What does the "connect through" clause do here?

That answer, and the linked documentation, explain that sets up the proxy authentication, allowing a normal user to connect with their own password as CIDBADMIN[SAMPLE_SCHEMA]/cidbadmin_passwd in that case - obviously you'd use your own team member's user IDs and your new schema instead. You can also read more here. If you are still stuck maybe ask about that on Database Administrators, as it's off-topic here really.

Also the documentation refers to 'middle tier server' but that's a logical server, like e.g. WebLogic Server or WIldFly, not a physical server. JNDI/JDBC can still connect directly to the schema, or that can also use its own proxy user. If you are just connecting to the database from e.g. SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you don't need any extra hardware or software.

@HussainAkbar, you have no need for a second server. You just need to grant the "connect through" priv and connect as Alex Poole has explained. It requires nothing you don't already have in place.

You can create a ROLE for your developers and after they log in, they can alter session to this user who will be the owner of the development objects, for example:
1 - Your developers will log in to the DB.
2 - Run the command: alter session set current_schema=DEVELOPER_USER;
3 - From now on, every object created will be owned by DEVELOPER_USER.
4 - Regarding permissions, you can create a trigger or job that grants permissions when needed.
It is better to grant create any table, as this allows them to create tables for ANY user, which can be a big problem.
